# \usetikzlibrary{positioning} in an expl3 package but PGF Math Error: Unknown function `of'

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, positioning, packages, expl3

EDIT: The problem I was encountering was due to a regex replace, which I did not include in the original question.  The problem is that I was replacing spaces in a token list with a control space `\`.  (I shouldn't have done this, and have since resolved the problem via the answer provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358544/78866)).  The first issue is that the control space in a `tikz` option/property  seems to allow that control space `\`.  That's why everything was working for me until I flipped things around with the `right=of nodename`.  Apparently, `tikz` does not like that control space after the `=`.  The second issue is that the error message give no indication that the space is a problem.  Instead, the error message seems to indicate that `of` is unrecognized, which suggests that the the control space is recognized as a normal space.

Unfortunately, I did not include these details originally, because the error message gave no indication of the space (modified by the regex) being the issue.  Fixing the regex, fixed the problem because the normal space from the token list that underwent a regex replace maintained the correct space.

---

Inside an `expl3` package, I am using `tikz` and loading `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`.  The reason for this is to transition from the deprecated `right of=nodename` to the current `right=of nodename` which requires the `positioning` library.

I used the solution here ([Using of \usetikzlibrary in an expl3 package fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57428)) to fix the usage of various `tikz` libraries within the `expl3` package.  Everything worked fine until I loaded the `positioning` library and then try to use the `right=of nodename` notation.  It gives me there error: `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'of' (in 'of nodename')`.

I know that the library is installed correctly on my system because I can use the notation in a standard `article` document and use it without error.  The issue seems to be connected to `expl3`, `tikz`, and `positioning` in a package, but I'm not really sure how to diagnose the problem further or fix it.

Obligatory MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{some-package.sty}

\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage
    % Package name
    {some-package}
    % Release date
    {2017/03/15}
    % Release version          
    {1.0}
    % Description
    {some package}

\RequirePackage{l3regex}%
\RequirePackage{xstring}%
\RequirePackage{xparse}%

\RequirePackage{tikz}%
%%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%%%%%%FIX - PATCH FOR LOADING LIBRARIES
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd
  {\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists}
  {\input #1}
  {%
    \@pushfilename
    \input #1 %
    \@popfilename
  }
  {}{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\makeapicture}{ }
{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node (test) [fill,inner~sep=2pt,label={[left~of~=~test]test}] at ( 4 , 3 ) {};% This works fine

        \node (test2) [fill,inner~sep=2pt,label={[left=of~test2]test2}] at ( 4 , 3 ) {};% This will give the error

    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{some-package}

\begin{document}

    \makeapicture

\end{document}
```

Importantly, loading the `positioning` library does not cause any errors.  It is only once I define a node using the non-deprecated notation that the error gets triggered.  It seems as though the `positioning` library is simply not loaded or something.

EDIT: I thought that perhaps the order of the libraries caused the problem and tried `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` first, last, and in between each other library, but this did nothing.

EDIT2:  `expl3` code is not included in this example because it has no issues.  Several document commands and internal command sequences, however, set up `tikzpicture`s and create `\nodes`.  All was working well until I decided to convert from the deprecated `right of=nodename` to the `positioning` version `right=of nodename`, as I mentioned at the top.  Literally, the only change that I made from a completely working package to one with this error is a) include the `positioning` library and b) change the location syntax.

Also, changing this section:

```
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd
  {\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists}
  {\input #1}
  {%
    \@pushfilename
    \input #1 %
    \@popfilename
  }
  {}{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%
```

to

```
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd
  {\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists}
  {\input #1}
  {%
    \@pushfilename
    \input #1 %
    \@popfilename
  }
  {}{}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%

\ExplSyntaxOn
```

does not work either.

Comment: That's not an MWE. We can't produce the error you report if we try to compile it. But you need to switch `expl3` syntax off before processing the Ti*k*Z stuff. `left of` is going to be read as `leftof` because spaces are not spaces. It isn't obvious why you want the `expl3` syntax here at all, but you certainly don't want it for Ti*k*Z.

Comment: What is the fix to do? The link you gave has nothing to do with `expl3`.

Comment: Switch the syntax off before loading the libraries and defining the macro which needs Ti*k*Z. Ti*k*Z's syntax is fundamentally allergic to L3's. It relies on spaces being correct.

Comment: I guess you mean http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57424/using-of-usetikzlibrary-in-an-expl3-package-fails?rq=1.

Comment: What the patch does affects the loading of the libraries. It doesn't 'fix Ti*k*Z to work in the L3 environment'.

Comment: I accidentally included the wrong link, sorry.  Yes, that was the correct URL.  Secondly, this is a minimal example and all the `expl3` stuff from the package is irrelevant here, however it is necessary for the package which is why it is included here.  If I put the library includes before `\ExplSyntaxOn` I get the same error.  Lastly, the spaces are included in my example with ~.  (I accidentally forgot to type them and edited probably after you read it).  Updating the example with `filecontents` package so that is is completely compile-able.

Comment: Just put the macro definition inside `\ExplSyntaxOff ... \ExplSyntaxOn`. You can load the libraries using the fix with L3 active. You just can't define your macro with it active, because you need Ti*k*Z's parser to work there.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox,tikz}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd
  {\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists}
  {\input #1}
  {%
    \@pushfilename
    \input #1%
    \@popfilename
  }
  {}{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {a};
  \node [left=of a] {b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The fix fixes the input of the libraries. It is not a general fix for the use of Ti*k*Z code when `expl3` syntax is active. That would be extremely difficult, if not impossible, since the two syntaxes are fundamentally allergic to each other. Ti*k*Z essentially uses its own parser and relies on things being as it expects.

The solution is to turn the syntax off before defining your macro, if required.

```
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand\makeapicture{}
{%
  \tizk{...}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
```